# Preview plugin store details

Tags: plugin-development

How can I preview how a new WordPress plugin, which I have not yet submitted for review, will look in the plugins store, e.g. the tile with meta information, logo, compatibility information etc.?

When I install my new plugin locally, it appears in the list of installed plugins, but without a "details" link, and I do not know how to mock its appearance in the store at `/wp-admin/plugin-install.php`.

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a thing, a good place to ask would be the WP Core slack in the #meta channel